# Add watermark to all videos in a folder and enable it only during certain time intervals

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm making a batch file to watermark all my videos in a folder using FFMPEG, I have to place the watermark at 1/3 of the duration of the video, I currently have this, it worked individually but I can't seem to make it work for the whole folder, what am I doing wrong? Also, is there a way to enable the watermark multiple times? once at 1/3 of the duration, another at 2/3 of the duration.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%I in ("%~dp0\water\*.mp4") do (
   for /F "delims=" %%I in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries format^=duration -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 %%I.mp4 2^>^&1') do set "duration=%%I"
   'ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i Watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/10[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-3:enable='between(t,%duration%/3,(%duration%/3)+2)'[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -codec:a copy "%~dp0\out\%%~nI.mp4"'
)
endlocal
pause
```

Thanks a lot for all the help I've received during these days, it really helped me to improve, although I still have a long way to go.

Comment: Why `[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0]`? Not needed. For also watermarking at 2/3rd duration, use `enable='between(t,%duration%/3,(%duration%/3)+2)+between(t,%duration%*2/3,(%duration%*2/3)+2)'` . Show the full console output of an execution where it didn't work.

Comment: This is the output, basically what it says it's that ffmpeg.exe is not recognized as a command                                                                                                              `"'ffmpeg.exe" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.'
"'ffmpeg.exe" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
"'ffmpeg.exe" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the interval-based watermarking fixed and only needed in batch mode? You could alternatively leave the videos in their original format and then serve them with dynamic watermarking (especially useful if you need to apply the watermark during different intervals, different watermark manipulations, etc.

For example, the following URL will take the original video dog.mp4 and apply the watermark cloudinary_icon as overlay during 3 intervals: 2-4 seconds, 6-8 seconds, 10-12 seconds. The watermark is applied with different opacity settings in each intervals - 20%, 40%, 60% (o_20,o_40,o_60).

http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/l_cloudinary_icon,so_2,eo_4,o_20/l_cloudinary_icon,so_6,eo_8,o_40/l_cloudinary_icon,so_10,eo_12,o_60/dog.mp4

Comment: The comment above solved my interval based issue, now I just need to find a way to properly apply the watermark to a folder, my solution was to wrap the operations needed to dynamically watermark into a For, it didn't work, I probably committed a syntax error somewhere or is there something I still don't know, basically, the code inside the outer For works to dynamically watermark ONE video (just change the %%I with the video name in the FFPROBE sentence) but now I want to apply that same operation to a whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the syntax had to be corrected so I split everything into their smallest components and made them work separately, then joined them together, there was an issue with the folder processing one, the tip to that was the " ' ", it was just a matter of paying attention to the error displayed by the CMD.